# How to replace a Pressure Reduction Valve and Shut off valve?

Tags: pressure

I got several quotes that I simply can't afford - $900+ to install a new quarter turn one inch shut-off valve and replacement of one inch Pressure Reduction Valve. I've done a few plumbing projects at my house but this is my first attempt to this type. The pressure is approx. 86 psi. He said the shut-off valve needs an upgrade to newer style. So may be I could just do the PRV replacement. The on/off valve works but he said it doesn't completely shutoff the water - it still trickles a little bit. He also said the PRV is a single union. Looking at the PRV and the wall against it, there's sufficient room for it to turn.

I went to HomeDepot and found a PRV that looks like it would fit perfectly. It's single union (like the current one). It's also the serviceable type and has a parts replacement kit. It looks like I don't have to cut anything off. Am I on the right track? I watched a youtube video demonstrating how to install similar PRV although dual union type. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1yDS6xD4Ppc

[image: PRV]
[image: PressureGuage]
[image: Pic3]
[[image: First Pic][1]] [image: Second Pic]

[image: pic4]
[image: pic5]

Comment: Are you sure there's one meter for three units?  That's unusual for townhouses. maybe one pit but three meters in it?  Also, gate valves are almost impossible to repair. The brass gate and seat is what corrodes, not the seals.

Comment: @Jack, yes we share the meter and split the bill. The house constructor did this in a complex of over 80 houses sharing meters every 3 or so houses per meter. Because of this oddity the HOA decided to pay for water and sewage and we pay a fixed amount included in our monthly HOA dues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the shut off valve works there is no reason to replace it unless the piping has to be removed to replace the PRV, In that case you should install a new valve.  Looking at the top picture the PRV has a union nut that can be loosened and dropped down on the valves inlet. I would shut off the on/off valve, loosen the union nut and drop,it down to see if the line above is flexible enough to allow the PRV to be removed. If it is, you could remove the existing PRV and install a new one of the same type that should be the same dimensions as the old PRV. If there is not enough room to turn the existing PRV then the copper pipe above may need to be cut. Post a picture of the piping by pulling the camera back a little so we can see what the piping configuration is. A better picture may allow a different procedure if necessary.

After reading more of the answers and statements made by you and others I have to ask "why is the cost you mentioned too high if there are 3 town houses involved". Can't the other 2 townhouses share in the cost to have a licensed plumber do the work.

Also, looking at the bottom picture showing the horrible piping arrangement done by someone who is obviously not a professional plumber or who should not be one, I would hire a plumber to correct that piping disaster and who could do the job correctly adding more isolation valves and unions for making future work easier. This would make the plumber responsible for an extended shutdown if there were to be problems.

You stated in your original post that you may just try to rebuild that shut off valve since you  watched a video on U-tube. Was that a video for a "gate valve" which I believe your is and I don't think they can be field repaired.

One last statement, if the 86# is the highest pressure you observe I would probably accept that as the norm unless there have been problems associated with that pressure. Mine has been 75-80 psi for 24 years with no adverse affects.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added more pics. The on/off valve works but he said it doesn't completely shutoff the water - it still trickles a little bit. He also said the PRV is a single union.

Comment: I read the metering  to mean that there's one valve before the meter, then the meter and then a manifold with three pull offs  to the three townhouses. So each unit would then have it's own shutoff valve and PRV.....  a crazy way to do it.. maybe the same guy that did the last picture. :-)

Comment: Here's the youtube video I'm referring to. The valve looks like what I have, no? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GiNpQohuCA4&t=186s

Comment: @candoit the valve in the video is not a gate valve but the one installed that is shown in uour  pictures is a gate valve. Yours can not be repaired .

Comment: @JACK, yes, each townhouse has it's own shutoff valve and PRV. No house has it's own meter. Each meter in our complex is shared among several townhouses such that any replacement of a townhouse shutoff valve requires at-least 2 days advanced notification of the upcoming work.

Comment: There's info on how to fix or rebuild a gate valve. Since mine works and the issue is that it does not completely shutoff water flow, the author opines that this scenario indicates sediment build up and there're tricks to fix this in place. https://www.commercial-industrial-supply.com/resource-center/how-to-rebuild-a-gate-valve/

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edit adding the pictures, I think your best bet is to replace the PRV and the shutoff valve. The shutoff valve still trickles when turn off and that's a bad sign. It means it's corroding inside and you'll have trouble when ever you need to turn off the water for replacing cartridges, faucets, etc. The valve could even brake when turned off and you won't be able to turn the water back on. You'd need to shut your water off at the street/water meter to replace it.

Your PRV does have a single union with that bottom nut but I doubt there will be enough "flex" in the 1" copper lines to get the clearance to unscrew the PRV from the top pipe unless the shutoff valve is cut out. I would completely remove the shutoff valve cutting it right at the valve to safe as much of the pipe as possible. Now you should be able to unscrew the PRV valve from the top threaded connector. Get a new PRV similar to your existing one and a ball shutoff valve. If you get a single union PRV valve, put a union on the "flow in" side of you new shutoff valve so you have a little flexibility in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your insights. I'm now dreading this project. Our townhouses share meters (3 houses to a meter) and if I turn off the water at the meter and make a blunder or take too long to finish the project due to complications or being a novice, I'll be in big trouble with my neighbors, e.g. messing up my shutoff valve requiring turning the water off at the meter for more than a few hours.